# wp-cli doesn't find and wordpress installation

Tags: wp-cli

I wanted to try wp-cli, downloaded the phar and installed it by moving it to ~/bin which is in my path.
Then wp --info works, but maybe shows insufficient information. (e.g. no php path, though it is running, so php is there ...)
Any other actions I tried so far were unsuccessful, alsways resulting in 'no wordpress installation found' Specifying --path or --url didn't change anything. The result is the same for a multisite or non-multisite installation. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
PHP binary:
PHP version:    5.3.27
php.ini used:   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.14.0-alpha
```

(added `wp --info` output)

Comment: Please post the full output from `wp --info`.

Comment: Sorry for only responding now @scribu . The output of wp info is as follows: `PHP binary:
    PHP version:    5.3.27
    php.ini used:   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
    WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
    WP-CLI global config:
    WP-CLI project config:
    WP-CLI version: 0.14.0-alpha`

Comment: Are you running your `wp` commands from a WordPress directory?

Comment: It would be good to also post the exact error output, when running a normal command, such as `wp core version`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If no `--path` is passed, WP-CLI defaults to the current directory and looks for the `wp-includes/version.php` file.

So, make sure that the directory you're in has such a file:

```
$ ls wp-includes
$ cat wp-includes/version.php
$ wp core version
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that I thought going to/ specifying the base wird would be enough (where index.php is) though /wordpress as the directory with the actual installation had to be specified directly.